# Using jsGrid as a local standalone application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I'm looking for ways to use `jsGrid` (http://js-grid.com) as local application.
I've found `basic.html` in `demos` folder from git-project and I noticed that changes made to the example datagrid are not committing (after refreshing a local copy of `basic.html` all changes revert to initial values). As far as I understand changes made to the table are in memory and main script doesn't save them to `db.js` where datasource (json-dictionary `clients`) is located. And as confirmation I found that implementation of `updatingClient`-function in `db.js` is empty (due to obvious in-memory realization).

Questions I want to ask:

1) How could I make this application to use external but local datasource? Should it be some kind of this pseudocode in `db.js`:
`db.clients = csv2json('clients.csv')` (assuming there is an additional jquery-plugin to do this task) ? Are there any more convenient approaches?

2) If the first question is reasonable how should I implement the `updateClient` function considering using by multiple users simultaneously? Is it possible?

3) I need some kind of time logging of actions performed on the datagrid. Should it be implemented by binding certain elements to log-functions on main page via click events? If so, how could I get time stamps from these functions?

Comment: Have you seen that this page http://js-grid.com/samples/ provides links to sample projects for js-grid with different backends?

Comment: yes, but due to some restrictions I'm able to use none of them. I need essentially a local file as database like sqlite or csv. The load is about five users.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html), you will have apache, PHP and MySQL - all local.

Otherwise, you can install sqlite or [Codernitydb](http://labs.codernity.com/codernitydb/quick.html) (better), which are local databases that do not require Internet access.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to do this.on target machines.